# Alternate formatting for Oracle GROUPING-type subtotals?

Tags: oracle, formatting, grouping

Typical GROUPING/ROLLUP results in Oracle-flavored SQL tends to go like this:

```
C   PROMO_ID    S_SALES 
- ---------- ---------- 
C        497   26094.35  
C        498    22272.4  
C        499    19616.8  
C       9999   87781668  
C            87849651.6
```

....with the column being totaled or subtotaled (C, in this case) being explicitly in the total/subtotal row. Now, I can fill that NULL easily enough, making it look like this by putting a GROUPING inside of a case statement:

```
 C     TOTAL 87849651.6
```

But it seems like it ought to be extremely easy to change the formatting for that total/subtotal row, to something like:

```
             87849651.6
```

or

```
TOTAL FOR C  87849651.6
```

However, for the life of me, I can't figure it out without going full-on row_num or something. Am I missing something obvious, or is this just a bit of formatting Oracle doesn't like doing?

Comment: You are, indeed, missing something obvious. You can use `GROUPING_ID` in a `CASE` expression in `SELECT` to get those labels. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions063.htm

Comment: Doh! Thank you. Even has the same test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING_ID` and `CASE` expressions to control what appears in the total rows. For example:

```
select   case grouping_id(deptno) when 0 then lpad(to_char(deptno), length('Grand Total'))
                                  else 'Grand Total' end as deptno, 
         sum(sal) as total_salary
from     scott.emp
group by rollup(deptno)
;

DEPTNO      TOTAL_SALARY
----------- ------------
         10         8750
         20        10875
         30         9400
Grand Total        29025
```

`grouping_id` can also be used to control the order of rows; for example, if you wanted the grand total at the top instead of the bottom, you could `order by grouping_id(deptno) desc, deptno`.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions063.htm